# API Rest Custom Post Type doesn't return all data

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

My friend has an site with WordPress 4.6.3, after Wordpress REST API vers 2 plugin was installed, added add_action() to function.php to enable API REST to custom post type.

With this http://www.mysite.it/wp-json/wp/v2/portfolio
json contains only 10 data insted 71.

How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: search for info about pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default WordPress return 10 posts per pages. To change the number of posts per page you should query `http://www.mysite.it/wp-json/wp/v2/portfolio/?per_page=71`. The max is 100 posts per request.